# RegEx Expression Help in Google Analytics Goals

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am trying to set up some goals in Google Analytics and I have everything but one of them working.

I need to know how to "cut off" an expression essentially.

So I have pages that are structured like the following where the CLIENT-NAME portion is dynamic based on client being viewed:

STEP 1 - `/client/CLIENT-NAME/`

STEP 2 - `/client/CLIENT-NAME/product/`

STEP 3 - `/client/CLIENT-NAME/cart/`

STEP 4 - `/client/CLIENT-NAME/checkout/`

STEP 5 - `/client/CLIENT-NAME/success/`

I created expressions for all of the above except the first one.

The following expression works for all of my pages except the top one:

`/client/.*/product/`

Insert `cart/checkout/success` where `product` is for any of the other funnel steps to be successful.

What I want is an expression that covers that step 1/top option and ignores anything that trails after that last / after CLIENT-NAME because if we count that, everything that follows counts for a different event type and the number is inflated quite a bit since it's counting pageviews that are for other steps in my funnel.

Is this possible in GA?

Comment: Try `/client/([^/]+)/?$`

Comment: If you just match `/client/CLIENT-NAME/`without an event you have to know for sure this will/could only happen once within a whole list of events for the client. Imo,  Its better to use a single event on all the clients. Use the event that best describes what it is you want to track. Using _nothing_  like this `/client/([^/]+)/?$` tells you absolutely nothing. But, if its just a one time header, then ok.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked perfectly, thank you so much!